# How to build a comprehensive website that has many components with play 2 with Java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, playframework-2.0, liferay

I have many websites build with Liferay. The reason I used Liferay or portlet based framework is that the nature of the websites. Usually, each page page display multiple content coming from different providers using rest web services. For example, the home page will display news coming from new provider, videos coming from other provider, and music coming from another provider, and so on, I guess you got the idea. I usually design a portlet for each content provider and reuse them as needed. Now coming to my question, I would like to use play 2 with Java to build such websites and from what I have understood so far is that I need to have a model that contains all of these data and send it to my template to be rendered. For example, /index will send the request to the controller.index() and then I have to populate a model that includes all the data: news, videos, and music, then return OK(template(model)) to send the model to the template to be rendered. The problems I see with this way is that The model will be huge which includes all kinds of data structure, and since content retrieval is different from one content type to the other it will make the code very complex and I can kiss reusalbilty goodbye.

Perhaps there is another way to build this, or maybe I didn't understand Play very well and Play is not suitable for this kind of websites. I think I'm not the first one who faced this before and I will appreciate your kind help. Please note that I'm not looking to start a debate on X vs Y, I just want to understand how to use play to build a website with rich content.

Thanks,

Iyad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play is suitable for this kind of job as much as any other web-framework, anyway first you need to get some general experience on it and next... project your application i.e. with some diagram tool, finally you can start coding.

The way how will you design your model(s) depends on you, personally I'd create a separate model for each data type - then collect them in one data model (not persisted) to pass it easily to the view, anyway that's just a tip of iceberg.

Comment: Thank you biesior for your reply.